# get the client's IP address in ASP.NET MVC iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use the following code when using iis

```
 string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

replay ip 192.168.1.1
guide me

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: `192.168.1.1` must be your IP. If someone else hits your application with a different IP it will be different. There is nothing wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use HttpRequest.ServerVariables to get the IP address of a client in ASP.NET MVC. The REMOTE_ADDR variable gives the IP address of the client.

You can directly use the below method to your controller page and call it from your view or wherever you need it.

```
public string GetIp()  
{  
    string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))  
{  
    ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];  
}  
    return ip;  
}
```

The above method returns the client IP address. It is better to use this method than the Request.UserHostAddress() because UserHostAddress sometimes may capture the IP address of user's proxy.

HttpRequest.ServerVariables not only get the IP address but returns any other metadata about the client browser and other details including details about the client browser, server, user, and URLs. Some of the common metadata include server name, server software, server port, logged in user, cookies info, header info, HTTPS info, authenticated user and authentication method, and others.

Comment: It is possible from the settings IIS